# Custom php Add to Cart from Search String

Tags: php, mysql

hope someone can help with this.

I currently have an "Add to Cart" option from individual Product pages on my site, which sends "pid" as a variable to the cart page and works perfectly.  The bit of code on my cart page that takes the pid is as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
```

However, in not wanting to re-write a new code I'd like to just change how $pid is obtained as I know it works throughout the rest of the code, and I thought this would be the answer:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_code'])) {
$prodAdd = $_POST['product_code'];
$pid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$prodAdd' LIMIT 1'");
```

Can anyone see anything that is glaringly obvious with it?  If I force assign $pid as the product name it works fine and I can echo out $prodAdd so I can only assume it's a problem with my query, I can't for the life of me work out what as I've tried changing just about everything I can think of!

Oh, and if anyone can help I'd actually prefer the term to be LIKE rather than =, but any working code would suffice.

Many Thanks, Joe

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com).  Enjoy having your DB trashed.

Comment: @MarcB Sometimes I just want to quit PHP and walk away.  It's a losing battle as long as the Internet never throws away crappy tutorials.

Comment: As long as there's money to be made from selling ads on otherwise utterly pointless/useless pages, there'll be crap on the net.

Comment: Any pointers towards any helpful and not crap resources then?

Comment: @user1266648 There are very few good PHP tutorials. Function documentation on php.net is the place to start always.  For the core PHP functionality, the official docs almost always have good examples demonstrating good practice.  However, beware of the user-provided examples in the comments below them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I assume that your `product_code` is not stored in the `product_name` column:

```
$pid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_code='$prodAdd' LIMIT 1'");
```

We assume you are then fetching the row correctly.  (`$pid` is just a result resource...)

Please protect your database against SQL injection! Your code is highly vulnerable in its current form:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_code'])) {
  // At a minimum, escape $prodAdd with mysql_real_escape_string()
  // This is NOT OPTIONAL! YOU MUST DO THIS!
  $prodAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_code']);
  $pid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_code='$prodAdd' LIMIT 1'");

  if (!$pid) {
    // query error
    echo mysql_error();
  }
  else {
    // All results into $products (though you limited it to 1)
    $products = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pid)) {
      $products[] = $row;
    }

    // If you expect exactly one result, no need for a loop
    // $product = mysql_fetch_assoc($pid);

    // Get the value you need:
    var_dump($products);
  }
}
```

If you want this as a `LIKE`, just concatenate on `%`:

```
$pid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%$prodAdd%' LIMIT 1'");
```

Comment: Thank you, I apparently understand php a lot less that I thought I did.  It's for a closed site, passworded via htaccess and then by a "users" database so if anyone is pathetic enough to attack it I'll at least have an idea of who it is

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query return a result resource to be later processed buy other mysql function like `mysql_num_rows, mysql_fetch_array` , etc. Try adding these lines to your code:

```
$pid = mysql_fetch_assoc($pid);
$pid = $pid[0]['id'];
```

If your mysql_query is syntacticaly correct, you should get your pid. If it still doesnt work try `echo mysql_error();` to see what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and for the explanation. It appears to work with the mysql_fetch_array, but apparently the whole of my code is worthless anyway

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the **sql injection problem**, the problem you have, is that the query does not return the id but a resource on success.

You probably want to change it to something like (and add error handling...):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$prodAdd' LIMIT 1'");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pid =  $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's probably me implementing it wrong but I get invalid resource errors from mysql_fetch_assoc